# Ubuntu 14.04 getting log in auth.log

Tags: ubuntu, cron, logs, session

I am getting error in `/var/log/auth.log`

```
CRON: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
CRON: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Even I logged in with *xyz* user in Webmin and I am taking backup of a database as *xyz* user, but it show multiple time `user root@localhost` and *xyz* user does not show, when I checked `auth.log` file then I see there this log multiple time

```
CRON: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
CRON: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just cron running jobs in background as root. Nothing to worry about. You can check what jobs are running in `/etc/crontab` or by running `crontab -l` as root. It's probably just some regular checks for updates or something similar enabled by default in Ubuntu.

If you just want pam to not log these events, follow [this article](https://languor.us/cron-pam-unix-cron-session-session-opened-closed-user-root-uid0) to disable it.